# Regular expression replace text contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have this paragraph:

```
"This person name #Question1#, #Question2#, has #Question3# been drinking in the past two days."
```

I use regex to find an array of matching entries for `#Question[0-9]+#`, my question is, how can   utilise the regex feature to replace these `#Question[0-9]+#` with actual answers from my database.

Here is my code

```
        const string pattern = @"#Question([0-9]+)#";
        string input = template.GetPrintOut;
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
```

I can provide a dictionary of replacing string from database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Of course, use `Regex.Replace`:

```
var res = reg.Replace(text, match => { ....; return "reply"; });
```

In the match lambda you can recover the data based on the `match` value and return the reply accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am new to lambda expression. Could you please provide an example. Here is my regex  const string pattern = @"#Question([0-9]+)#";
            string input = template.GetPrintOut;
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);